# What method can I use just before deserialization in Django REST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have this serializer in Django REST:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_age')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'age')

    def get_age(self, obj):
        return obj.age * 100
```

Now that works fine for serialization.

But now I want it so that when I deserialize then it will `divide the age by 100`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373766/django-rest-framework-custom-serialize-a-field ?

Comment: @SimeonVisser This what i already have. That work for GET requests where i am serializing. but during deserializing how will it do the reverese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a custom field may be of use in this instance.

```
class AgeField(serializers.WriteableField):
    def to_native(self, age):
        return age * 100

    def from_native(self, age):
        return int(age) / 100

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = AgeField(source='age')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Deserialize a dictionary of attributes into an object instance.
        You should override this method to control how deserialized objects
        are instantiated.
        """
        if instance is not None:
            instance.update(attrs)
            instance.update({'age', attrs['age'] / 100})
            return instance
        return attrs

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'age')
```

In this example, let's say that the age is 10. In your serializer, you would display the following:

```
[
    {
        "field1": "value",
        "field2": "value",
        "age" : 100
    },
]
```

The `to_native` method will show the value as 100 as the form on the page. However, when submitting 100 as the value, the `from_native` will trigger (with `age` being unicode), and then be divided by 100, storing to the database as 10. Is this what you are looking for?

Or, if you are talking about strictly deserializing, the `restore_object` code is likely what you are looking for in combination with `to_native`.

Comment: thanks so , it means i can use either custom field or restore_object . i have to use both